# update form not populating from existing data in mysql database

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi im trying to populate my Update form with existing data from mysql database so I can modify the data and save it back to the mysql database. Everything is working and no errors but its not populating at all. Thanks in advance

Index.php

```
<?php
require('includes/mysqli_connect.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM item";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
WHILE($items = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<h3>" . $items['item_id'] . "</h3>";
    echo "<p>" . $items['title'] . "</p>";
    echo "<a href=\"modify.php?id=" . $items['item_id'] . "\">Modify Item</a>";
    echo "<span> </span>";
    echo "<span> </span>";  
    echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $items['item_id'] . "\">Delete Item</a>";
}
?>
```

Modify.php

```
<?php 
require('includes/mysqli_connect.php');
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {  
include('includes/mysqli_connect.php');         
$q = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_id = '$_GET[item_id]'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$items = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
 /* or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc)) */;
}
?>
<h1>Modify item</h1>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">        
<h4>Selling format:</h4>
<h4>Auction:
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $items['auction']; ?>" name="inputauction"></h4>       
<h4>Buy Now:
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $items['buynow']; ?>" name="inputbuynow"></h4>
<h4>Select category:</h4>   
<select name="cat_id"> 
<?php
include('includes/mysqli_connect.php');
$q = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM category ".
"ORDER BY cat_id";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
{ 
echo "<option value=\"".$row['cat_id']."\">".$row['cat_name']."</option>\n  ";
}
?>
</select>   
<h4>Title:
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" 
value="<?php echo $items['title']; ?>"   name="inputtitle"></h4>    
<h4>Description:</h4>
<textarea rows="7" cols="27" value="<?php echo 
$items['description']; ?>"  name="inputdescription" wrap="physical"></textarea> 
<p><a href="#" onclick="window.open('uploadwin.php', 'newwindow', 
'width=200, height=150'); return false;">
<h4>Click here to upload picture</h4></a></p>
<h4>Auction Start Price:
<input type="text" size="15" maxlength="15" 
value="<?php echo $items['auct_price']; ?>" name="inputauct_price"></h4>    
<h4>Buynow Price:
<input type="text" size="15" maxlength="15" 
value="<?php echo $items['buynow_price']; ?>" name="inputbuynow_price"></h4>
<h4>Duration:
<select name="inputduration">
<option value="<?php echo $items['1 Day']; ?>">1 Day</option>
<option value="<?php echo $items['3 Days']; ?>">3 Days</option>
<option value="<?php echo $items['5 Days']; ?>">5 Days</option>
</select></h4>  
<h4>Quantity:
<input type="text" size="15" maxlength="15" 
value="<?php echo $items['qty']; ?>" name="inputqty"></h4>
<h4>Item Location:
<input type="text" size="15" maxlength="15" 
value="<?php echo $items['item_location']; ?>" name="inputitem_location"></h4>      
<h4>Accepted Payment:</h4>  
<h4>PayPal:
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $items['paypal']; ?>" name="inputpaypal"></h4>     
<h4>EFT:
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $items['EFT']; ?>" name="inputEFT"></h4>   
<h4>Postage:</h4>
<h4>Pickup:
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $items['pickup']; ?>" name="inputpickup"></h4>     
<h4>Post Interstate:
<input type="checkbox" 
value="<?php echo $items['post_nationally']; ?>" name="inputpost_nationally"></h4>      
<h4>Post National:
<input type="checkbox" value="
<?php echo $items['post_internation']; ?>" name="inputpost_internation"></h4>       
<h4>Post Internation:
<input type="checkbox" 
value="<?php echo $items['buyerpay_post']; ?>"   name="inputbuyerpay_post"></h4>
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['item_id']; ?>" />      
<input type="submit" value="Modify" name="submit">
</form><br><br>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$u = "UPDATE `ICADBS504A`.`item` SET `auct_price` = '$_POST[inputauct_price]', 
`buynow_price` ='$_POST[inputbuynow_price]', `title` = '$_POST[inputtitle]', 
`description` =  '$_POST[inputdescription]', `qty` = '$_POST[inputqty]', 
`img_path` = '$imgpath',  `item_location` = '$_POST[inputitem_location]',         
`auction` = '$_POST[inputauction]', `buynow` = '$_POST[inputbuynow]', 
`duration` = '$_POST[inputduration]', `pickup` = '$_POST[inputpickup]', 
`post_nationally` = '$_POST[inputpost_nationally]', 
`post_internation` = '$_POST[inputpost_internation]', 
`buyerpay_post` = '$_POST[inputbuyerpay_post]', `cat_id` = '$cat', 
`paypal` = '$_POST[inputpaypal]', `EFT` =  '$_POST[inputEFT]' WHERE 
`item_id` = $_POST[item_id]";
mysqli_query($u) or die(mysqli_error());
echo "Item has been modified!";
header("Location: index.php");
}
include('includes/footer.html'); 
?>
```

Comment: Is it the `Modify.php` page at the end `$u` query that is not working? Or what is not populating?

Comment: correct its the $u that should be populating the form for updating, form shows up but empty completely

Comment: So your `isset($_POST['submit'])` condition is met but none of the `$_POST` values are populating, correct?

Comment: that is correct I believe

Comment: Since you're using `modify.php?id` you're missing `$_GET['id']` Or, you may have meant to use `WHERE item_id = '$_GET[id]'";`

Comment: on the index file, the get['id'] works correctly, I can press the link and the correct ?id=17  shows up but the form is completely empty

Comment: $q = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_id = '$_GET[item_id]'";   is that what you mean Fred, thats allready in my modify file near the top.

Comment: Yes, but your PHP parameter is `id` in `modify.php?id` <= there. You don't have a `$_GET['id']` anywhere, so that's why it's failing or is contributing to it. Try changing `WHERE item_id = '$_GET[item_id]'` to `WHERE item_id = '$_GET[id]'`

Comment: Plus, in your UPDATE you have `= $_POST[item_id]` try using `= $_GET[item_id]` `or $_GET[id]` - Something is not matching.

Comment: That fixed it mate, not every this is showing 50% but I can work that out, Cheers again Mr Fred

Comment: That could be why its not showing all data, I'll try that too

Comment: I changed from $_POST[item_id] to $_GET[id], same result as that which is only showing data in all my text boxes but not any of the check boxes

Comment: Do you get data from checkboxes that are checked?

Comment: no non of them at all, only getting data from text boxes, the value I set on the original submit is the letter 'Y' to indicate yes as data on the check boxes

Comment: You're welcome @Vasko You'll get the rest I'm sure, *cheers*

Comment: Cheers Fred thank very much mate!!!!! have a great day, I owe you 2 favors lol

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help, *cheers* - I should get me one of those fancy *Buy me a beer button* lol! (I'm kidding of course, *lol!*).